# Background Worker won't receive CancellationPending in c# WinForm application

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, backgroundworker

I have a problem with backgroundworkers in my WinForm application.
Here is my scenario:
I have a background workers that starts in OnLoad form event. Then I have a checkbox on the form to stop/start the workers.
When I uncheck the box the event call the cancelAsync() method, but the worker don't receive CancellationPending.
To debug this problem I have tried to add a Button on the form that perform the same as the CheckedChanged event, in this case it works???!!!

This is a snippet of my code:

The workers ...

```
private void BwMB_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    bwMBExitEvent.Reset();

    bool loop = true;
    while (loop)
    {
        if (bwMB.CancellationPending)
        {
            loop = false;
        }

        ... other code ...
    }

    e.Cancel = true;
    bwMBExitEvent.Set();
}
```

The CheckedChanged event ...

```
private void checkBoxModBus_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {   
        if (checkBoxModBus.Checked)
        {
            if (!bwMB.IsBusy)
                bwMB.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            if (bwMB.IsBusy)
            {
                bwMB.CancelAsync();
                bwMBExitEvent.WaitOne();
            }
        }
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
     }
}
```

And the button click event for debug ...

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bwMB.CancelAsync();
    bwMBExitEvent.WaitOne();
}
```

When I click on the button the worker receives the cancellation signals and exit loop setting the bwMBExitEvent (ManualResetEvent). In this way the click event WaitOne end waiting.
When I uncheck the box the worker, stop running, but don't receive the signal, so don't ends the loop and the event is not set. The CheckedChanged's WaitOne never ends.

*Please excuse any English grammar or spelling issues.*

Comment: You don't need the event with BGW. You don't need BGW in the first place, it's a legacy component completely replaced by Task, `async/await` and `Progress<T>`

Comment: I second Panagiotis. See:  [async](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)

Comment: If you have multiple BGW's, are you sure you are monitoring the correct one? Check the sample on the [DoWorkEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.doworkeventargs?view=netframework-4.7.2) documentation: it casts `sender` to BGW to ensure it works with the correct sender

Comment: *Remove* all attempts to "fix" the BGW and try with a clean implementation - no `loop`, no `bwMBExitEvent`, no `e.Cancel = true;`. If you want to exit from `DoWork`, `if (bwMB.CancellationPending){ return;}` is enough. You'll have to explicitly cancel each BGW though, and can't await for them to finish. That's trivial with Tasks on the other hand

Comment: It looks like a timing issue (race condition). When you call WaitOne you will block processing of events, including those of the Bgw.

Comment: To give you better answers: Will you insist on fixing the BGW approach or are you open to answers suggesting how to use async/await and Task for what you are trying to do?

Comment: That WaitOne() call is a deadlock waiting to happen.  Never block the UI thread.  Use Debug > Windows > Threads to debug the deadlock, you'll probably see the worker thread hanging on an Invoke call.  Can't complete when the UI thread goes catatonic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, BGW is obsolete, fully replaced by `async/await`, Tasks and `Progress<T>`. Tasks allow composition, continuations and cancellation, something that's quite complex with BGWs. I suspect the `bwMBExitEvent` event is used to implement a *continuation* after a BGW finishes.

The article [Async in 4.5: Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/) explains how cancellation and progress reporting work in .NET 4.5 and later (ie all supported versions).

That said, BGW has no problem with cancellation. I suspet the event,`loop` variables and other unseedn code end up causing race conditions.

Using 2, 4 or 10 cancellable tasks instead of BGW's though is easy.

- Multiple tasks can be started easily with [Task.Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.7.2).
- It's possible to await multiple tasks to finish without blocking with [Task.WhenAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netframework-4.7.2).
- Cancellation can be signaled to threads, tasks on asynchronous operations with [CancellationTokenSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Starting multiple tasks is easy :

```
private void StartTasks()
{
   _cts=new CancellationTokenSource();
  //Start each method passing a CancellationToken
   _tasks=new[]{
                 Task.Run(()=>WorkerMethod1(_cts.Token)),
                 Task.Run(()=>WorkerMethod2(_cts.Token)),
                  ...
               };
   //Enable the Cancel button
   Cancel.Enabled=true;
}
```

This code create N tasks and stores them in an array. It also creates a *new* CancellationTokenSource that can be used for signalling cancellation to all tasks or threads monitorint its tokens

To cancel the tasks with a button call [CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.cancel?view=netframework-4.7.2) and await for all tasks to complete :

```
private async void Cancel_Clicked(object sender,EventArgs args)
{
    if (_cts!=null)
    {
       lblStatus.Text = "Cancelling";
       //Signal a cancellation
        _cts.Cancel();
       //Asynchronously wait for all tasks to finish
        await Task.WhenAll(_tasks);
        _cts=null;           
       lblStatus.Text = "Cancelled";
    }
    //Disable the button
    Cancel.Enabled=false;
}
```

By using `async/await` the handler isn't blocking while waiting for the tasks to finish. It doesn't need `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` either, as execution resumes on the UI thread after `await`.

All the worker methods have to do is check the [CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.iscancellationrequested?view=netframework-4.7.2) flag :

```
private void WorkerMethod1(CancellationToken token)
{
    //If cancellation isn't requested
    while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        //Loop one more time
    }
}
```

Putting everything together :

```
//Hold active tasks
Task[] _tasks;

private void WorkerMethod1(CancellationToken token)
{
    //If cancellation isn't requested
    while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        //Loop one more time
    }
}

CancellationTokenSource _cts;

private void OnLoad(...)
{
    //Fire the tasks
    StartTasks();
}

private void StartTasks()
{
   _cts=new CancellationTokenSource();
  //Start each method passing a CancellationToken
   _tasks=new[]{
                 Task.Run(()=>WorkerMethod1(_cts.Token)),
                 Task.Run(()=>WorkerMethod2(_cts.Token)),
                  ...
               };
   //Enable the Cancel button
   Cancel.Enabled=true;
}

private async void Cancel_Clicked(object sender,EventArgs args)
{
    if (_cts!=null)
    {
       //Signal a cancellation
        _cts.Cancel();
       //Asynchronously wait for all tasks to finish
        await Task.WhenAll(_tasks);
        _cts=null;           
    }
    //Disable the button
    Cancel.Enabled=false;
}
```

Comment: Hi Panagiotis, thank you for yuor replay, i appreciate you. Next week, at office, I'll try to change my BackgroundWorker code with your suggestion. Then I'll write the results on this post.
Leonardo.